# change xxx-sources.jar download's directory in intellij idea in sbt projects

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

there is a **scala sbt project** that created by **intellij idea**, and I add `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.12.1"` into `build.sbt`.

`log4j-core-2.12.1.jar` was saved into `~/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/jars/`.
when I check **log4j-core** source code, intellij idea show:

[image]

I click **Download...** to download `source code`, I find `log4j-core-2.12.1-sources.jar` was saved in `~/.ideaLibSources/`.

[image]

but I want to save `log4j-core-2.12.1-sources.jar` to `~/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/srcs/`, and if I download `commons-io-2.6-sources.jar`, I want to save it into `~/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/srcs/`, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want sbt to download the sources into the ivy cache

1. go to the sbt options for your project in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | sbt
2. check Download: Library sources
3. refresh the sbt project

Then it will not be necessary to download these sources from IntelliJ.